# How to have multiple jQuery Image Swap Galleries on the same page?

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, swap, thumbnails

I have multiple image galleries that use the following code (simply view the demo at the following link).

However, when one clicks on the thumbnails of one gallery to change the large image preview - all the galleries change automatically to that large preview as well.

In short, the question is:

"How do I separate each gallery from each other so when the user clicks on the thumbnails of one specific gallery the large image preview of that gallery changes and not any other?"

JavaScript:

```
$("ul.thumb li a", $(".item")).click(function() {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
    $("#main_view img", $(".item")).attr({ src: mainImage });
    return false;       
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
   <h2>The Money Growing Door</h2>
   <div id="main_view">
     <img src="images/1.jpg" class="uks" alt="#" />
   </div>
   <ul class="thumb">
     <li><a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/colours/sinine.png" alt="#" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/colours/must.png" alt="#" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/colours/valge.png" alt="#" /></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, I repeat the same HTML and Javascript as seen in the code at: 
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/
Only I have multiple galleries on the same page.

Comment: $("ul.thumb li a", $(".item")).click(function() {
  var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
  $("#main_view img", $(".item")).attr({ src: mainImage });
  return false;  
 });
 
});

The html is: 

 <div class="item">
             <h2>The Money Growing Door</h2>
               <div id="main_view">
 
<img src="images/1.jpg"  class="uks" alt="#" />
$("ul.thumb li a", $(".item")).click(function() {
  var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
  $("#main_view img", $(".item")).attr({ src: mainImage });
  return false;  
 });
 
});

I will get the html on the next com.

Comment: I can not edit my own post as a newbie so I have to put the code in the comments, which is really bad

Comment: Anyhow here is the html:

  <div class="item">
             <h2>The Money Growing Door</h2>
               <div id="main_view">
 
<img src="images/1.jpg"  class="uks" alt="#" />
</div>


<ul class="thumb">
 <li><a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/colours/sinine.png" alt="#" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/colours/must.png"  alt="#" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/colours/valge.png"  alt="#" /></a></li>
 
</ul>
            
          </div>

Comment: I got you a possible solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically, I repeat the same HTML and
>   Javascript as seen in the code at:
>   http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/
>   Only I have multiple galleries on the
>   same page.

so I would think you have lots of `<ul class="thumb">`??

if so, then try

```
$("ul.thumb li a").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
    $(this).closest('.item').find("#main_view img").attr({ src: mainImage });
    return false;       
});
```

[quick demo](http://jsbin.com/evifa3/edit)